# Extract from XML with Nokogiri in ruby, from a div with br

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, nokogiri

I want to extract from an xml, the portion of text that is inside the label div, taking into account the carriage returns. Use the following code in ruby.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(xmlpost.content)
contenido = doc.css('div').css('span')
parrafo = Array.new()
contenido.each do |par|
  parrafo.push(par.text)
end
parrafo_json = parrafo.to_json
return parrafo_json
```

The problem is that in the array I store all text without carriage returns, and I would like to put in a different array position each portion of text separated with a carriage return.

For example, Suppose that I have this xml:

```
<div><span><br>example1</br><br>example2</br></span></div>
<div><span>example3</span></div>
```

When I run this on this code I'm building this array:

["example1example2","example3"]

and I want to take into account the br for this:

["example1","example2","example3"]

Comment: You should post a sample of the XML you are working on and the result you expect to get from it.

Comment: This is the problem. I'm edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

I hope I get what you expect to achieve properly. First of all, get rid of this php inside ruby:

```
parrafo = Array.new()
contenido.each do |par|
  parrafo.push(par.text)
end
```

This is how it to be rewritten in ruby:

```
parrafo = contenido.map(&:text)
```

Here we [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) every item in `contenido` to `par.text`. Now you have an array of texts. You might join them with carriage returns:

```
parrafo_with_cr = parrafo.join($/)
#⇒ "First line\nsecond line\n..."
```

The above will join lines using platform-agnostic separator `$/`. To join specifically with, say, `\n`:

```
parrafo_with_cr = parrafo.join("\n")
```

Hope it helps.

**UPD** For an updated question (break by `<br>` tags):

```
contenido = doc.css('div').css('span').map do |i|
  i.inner_html.split(/<br>/)
end.flatten - ['']
#⇒ [
#  [0] "example1",
#  [1] "example2",
#  [2] "example3"
#]
```

The latter `- ['']` here removes empty elements produced by `<br>` in at the very beginning of `<span>`s.

Sidenote: your HTML is not valid, `<br>` tag has no closing sibling.

Comment: Thanks. The solution rules, but the array is now so:
["<span><br>example1</br>","<br>example2</br></span>","<span>example3</span>"]
I only want the text.